# Estou redimensionando e definindo a página HTML de forma "correta"?

Tags: html, css3

Tenho uma dúvida que me mata na hora de criar sites, fiz um exemplo rápido aqui, após realizar algumas pesquisas e nenhuma me tira essa dúvida, não sei bem se estou no caminho correto, mas fiz uma página rápida, simples, mas pra exemplificar minha dúvida vai servir. A minha dúvida é se é errado, ou indiferente definir o tamanho da minha página dessa forma, e se existe alguma forma mais eficaz pra ajustar ao tamanho da tela do computador que vai visualizar, segue aqui o HTML e CSS, gostaria de uma atenção ao CSS, se a utilização de MARGIN-TOP, ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE, TOP, LEFT, estão sendo utilizadas corretamento? Se tiverem alguma dica, ou até mesmo um livro, artigo, algo que possa me guiar nesses conceitos, agradeço!

Segue o HTML e o CSS:

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

div.topo {
 margin-top:-8px;
 margin-left: -8px ;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:150px; 
 background-color: #fe5f55;
 z-index: 5;
}

div.topo h1{
 position: relative;
 top:-35px;
 font-size:70px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:consolas;
}

div.menu {
 position: relative;
 top:-70px;

}

div.menu ul{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left:-55px;
 font-size:25px;
 top:0px;
 text-align:center;
}

div.menu li{
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
 border: #600 1px solid;

}

div.menu ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: consolas;
 padding:30px;
 color:black;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover{
 color:blue;
}

div.lateral {
 top:150px;
 left:0px;
 height:100%;
 width:230px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: yellow;
}

div.lateral h2{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:30px;
 text-decoration: underline;
}


div.conteudo {
 margin-top: -17px;
 position: relative;
 width:1119px;
 height:700px;
 top:142px;
 left:222px;
 background-color: black;
}


div.titulo {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 25px;
 color:white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Big News</title>
 <meta chartset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="topo">
 <h1>Big News</h1>
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="">Início</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Notícias</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Downloads</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div><!-- Fim do topo -->

<div class="lateral"> 
 <h2>Updates</h2>

</div><!-- Fim da lateral -->

<div class="conteudo">
 <div class="titulo">
 <p> Aqui se encontra todo conteúdo da página, as laterais e o topo do site são fixos. </p>
 </div><!-- Fim do titulo -->


</div><!-- Fim do conteúdo -->




</div><!-- Fim do container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pesquise sobre "responsividade" e HTML5 (semântica). Seu site vai ficar bem melhor e adaptado à atualidade.

Answer (score 0):

Como o colega comentou, você está escrevendo html de uma forma desatualizada, para melhorar o entendimento, você precisa estudar responsividade, web semântica e novas técnicas de escrever layouts com css, usando flexbox ou gridlayout.

O html fica dessa forma:

```html
<html>
     <head>
       <title>Estructura basica Semantica en HTML5 y CSS3</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="description" content="Estructura basica Semantica en HTML5 y 
          CSS3 con Responsive Design" />
       <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />-->
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Estructura básica Semántica en HTML5 y CSS3</h1>
       <div class="content">
      
         <header>
           &lt;header&gt;
         </header>
      
         <nav>
           &lt;nav&gt;
         </nav>
      
         <section id="content">
           <section id="principal">
             &lt;section&gt;
             <article>
               &lt;article&gt;
             </article>
           </section>
           <aside>
             &lt;aside&gt;
           </aside>
         </section>
    
         <footer>
           &lt;footer&gt;
         </footer>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

e o css assim:

```css
/*
 * Il concetto imporatnte è che prima va fatto il css per il mobile
 * e poi con i MEDIA QUERY fare il css per il resto.
*/

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-size:62.5%;
  background:#212121;
  color:white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.content {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:2.5em;
}

h1 {
  color:#f60;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.25em auto;
  font-size:2em;
}
header, 
nav,
footer {
  background-color: #ed4c62;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#principal,
aside {
  background-color: #ed4c62;
  border-radius: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: .25em 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
article {
  background-color: #ebc555;
  border-radius: .5em;
  min-height: 140px;
  padding: .25em;
  margin:0 1em;
}
aside {
  margin-top:0.5em;
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: 44em) {
  h1 {
    font-size:5em;
  }
  #principal {
    width: 70%;
  }
  aside {
    width: 29%;
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

Nesse link fica visualmente bem definido, como devem ser as coisas:

https://codepen.io/cumboandrea/pen/Dtuho

Comment: Obrigado demais pela ajuda, vou estudar mais sobre responsividade, estou bem desatualizado, um abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Cara, evite fazer alinhamentos utilizando esses números "mágicos" em px, pois dessa forma o seu site só vai ficar corretamente alinhado ao tamanho da tela que você fez o desenvolvimento, exceto se você utilizar media queries, mas ainda é complicado... Atualmente é importante que o site mantenha sua aparência na maioria nos dispositivos pelo menos. Deixo como sugestão você estudar o sistema de grids do bootstrap por exemplo, que é poderoso se bem utilizado. Segue alguns links onde você pode estudar e tirar dúvidas:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

E caso queira se aprofundar mais depois de aprender sobre responsividade, recomendo estudar sobre como agradar ao usuário final, aprendendo algo sobre UI e UX.
Explicação básica do que se trata UI e UX:
   https://www.raffcom.com.br/blog/qual-a-diferenca-entre-ux-e-ui/

Bons estudos, nunca se deixe vencer pela frustração e boa sorte :)